# How to replace tabs for spaces in gedit?

Tags: gedit

If you create a file using gedit, which is configured to insert 4 spaces each time you press tab. Then for some reason you edit the file and some tabs get inserted (i.e. While editing on Windows). How can you replace those tabs back to spaces using gedit?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To do that you just need to use the replace form and search for: \t (backslash followed by t) then replace it with four spaces.

[Source](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+question/163516)

Comment: well, not in my gedit :)

Comment: I think I had to change settings in three places. Edit, preferences, editor, indentation. And preferences files when saved change tabs to spaces. And under project properties, indentation.

Comment: @oldfred I see, then I'd prefer my good old python :)

Comment: Those are one time changes. And if you have tabs the change on save mode converts tabs to spaces automatically.

Answer (score 4):

You can highlight, copy and paste a 'tab' from your file into the search and replace fields to achieve this in either direction tabs>spaces or spaces>tabs.